# Subscribe to observables on time interval with RxJs

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have list of observables. My target is to fire (subscribe) them with interval of one second. I have tried many options like RxJs  `forkJoin`, but subscriptions are fired at same time, or using RxJs `concat` - but in this case thay are fired one after another completes. Also tried to loop the list with `setTimeout`, but it didn't worked as well. How is that possible? I am using Angular v7 and RxJs

Example:

```
const observables: Observable<any>[] = [];
for (let i = 0; i < myCustomList; i++) {
    observables.push(MY_API_CALL)
}
forkJoin(observables).subscribe(() => {
    this._handleSuccess();
}, err => {
    this._handleError();
});
```

In DevTools I expect to see requests (MY_API_CALL) being fired one by another with one second interval

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use rxjs map operator, for example switchmap if you want the canceling effect:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { forkJoin, interval, pipe, of } from 'rxjs';
import { map, switchMap, take, delay } from 'rxjs/operators';
@Component({
  selector: 'get-request',
  templateUrl: 'get-request.component.html',
})
export class GetRequestComponent implements OnInit {
  totalAngularPackages;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const call1 = this.http.get<any>(
      'https://api.npms.io/v2/search?q=scope:angular1'
    );

    const call2 = this.http.get<any>(
      'https://api.npms.io/v2/search?q=scope:angular2'
    );

    const interval1 = of(true).pipe(
      delay(10000),
      switchMap(() => call1)
    );

    const interval2 = of(true).pipe(
      delay(1000),
      switchMap(() => call2)
    );

    forkJoin([interval1, interval2]).subscribe((data) => console.log(data));
  }
}
```

Through delay operator you can control mapping delay.

Comment: My observables are calls to API. I want to fire them with one second interval

Comment: I've saw updated, it waits for a second and yet again it fire them both at once

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-http-get-examples-51vxj5?file=app%2Fapp.component.html,app%2Fapp.module.ts,app%2Fcomponents%2Fget-request.component.ts,app%2Fcomponents%2Findex.ts

Comment: I stand correct, It is working fine

Comment: Good ok. I added a waterfall ss:) : https://prnt.sc/99BV8tIUm5Au

Answer (score 1):

```js
const { of, delay, switchMap, tap, forkJoin } = rxjs;

// Create an array of observables
const obs = Array.from({ length: 10 }, (_, i) => of(i));

// Map that array to an increasing delay
const delayedObs = obs.map((o, i) => of(null).pipe(
  delay(i * 1000),
  tap(() => { console.log('starting ' + i); }),
  switchMap(() => o)
));

forkJoin(delayedObs).subscribe(console.log);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/7.8.0/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

it seems you are using the wrong operator for your usecase

`forkJoin()`

- `signature: forkJoin(...args, selector : function): Observable`
- When all observables complete, emit the last emitted value from each

Instead you want to use observable `xxxMap` operators to combine observable streams together

`mergeMap()`

- merge multiple observables into one result observable stream, emitting values (`next()`) from the source observables as they arrive to the output observable.

`concatMap()`

- merge multiple observables after eachother into the output observable. Only starts emitting values of input2 when input1 completes()